# Xcode Error: "ld: framework not found..."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I've got an iOS project on Xcode that uses Firebase, which was downloaded through Cocoapods. Everything was working fine - running on both simulators and devices - until I tried to run the app on an iPad 7th generation simulator and this error was thrown:

```
ld: framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now the project won't build on any device or simulator. I navigated through the Pods folder to check if GoogleAppMeasurement had its framework and it does. Besides this one error, there's no frameworks highlighted in red (like some other related questions mention) or other indication of what could have gone wrong. 
Here's my pod file in case it helps:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'my project's name' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for my project's name
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

This same error has popped up on another one of my firebase-reliant projects and I've had no luck getting rid of it there either. Any suggestions on how to keep troubleshooting are welcome.